# Numeric solution of simple but possibly singular linear system

Tags: linear-solver

I have a simple (and small) linear homogeneous system $Ax=0$, where the entries of the $N\times M$ matrix $A$ are small integers. I do not need fancy methods which efficiently solve almost singular matrices and treat roundoff errors etc. But I need to know if a system is singular and also the general solution for underdetermined systems. It must be rock-solid. Any reference to such an algorithm is welcome. I am coding in C. Is SVD the way to go?

Comment: Are you looking for integer solutions as well? What is the size of $N$ and $M$? By "general solution", do you mean a basis of the null space of $A$?

Comment: Yes, essentially I mean a basis of the null space. Size of N and M can vary, where `N>M` and `M>N` is both possible . Typical size could be `N,M\sim 10`. I searched a bit further and found that 'reduced Row Echelon form' could be the solution. Since `A` has integer elements only rationals would appear and I could compute exact results. Anybody aware of an open implementation (any language).

Comment: I.e. I search an implementation of the Gaussian elemination for `NxM` matrices. I know that of Numerical recipies, but it is for `NxN`. I understand now that SVD would work. But it seems a bit overkill to me with the additional advantage that it would use floats and probably be to long to adopt it to integers/rationals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Integer Matrix Library](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~astorjoh/iml.html) is a C library that claims to be able to compute the null space of an integer matrix. See also [this answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42637/exact-computation-of-the-null-space-basis-of-an-integer-matrix/57582#57582) to the exact same question, which gives a list of libraries (including [PARI](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), which also can be called from C and is still being updated). You could also take a look at [LinBox](http://www.linalg.org/), even though it's written in C++.

Comment: The reference to IML was pretty useful to me. It does what I want. Also the question on MathOverflow is really the same.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution of your underdetermined system is that $x$ is a member of the nullspace of $A$.

To find the nullspace of $A$, the most numerically stable method is to use an SVD. See [Null-space of a rectangular dense matrix](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2510/null-space-of-a-rectangular-dense-matrix) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

The SVD will both
(1) tell you what the null space of your matrix is
(2) give you the pseudo-inverse of the matrix in the event that it is singular.
The SVD is, generally speaking, a very handy matrix factorization and for your stated purposes should definitely get the job done.

If you're determined to write the code yourself, [Trefethen and Bau's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898713617) has enough details to work from, either implementing the really bad way of finding the eigendecomposition of A*A or the proper way using bidiagonalization.

However, if you just happen to be working in C and don't feel the need to do it yourself, the [Wikipedia page for the SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) has a long list of libraries that will implement it for you, chief among which is the GNU Scientific Library. Or, a google search of "SVD c source code" turns up a couple results as well.