# Singular matrix - but SVD works - what does the eigenvalues mean? Find I the "dependent" lines?

Tags: lapack, eigenvalues, matrix

please can I ask a bit stupid question? I have a complex matrix *A* as a set of equations. I wanted to find the solution of *Ax=b* where *b* is vector of right-hand side. So I have called *zgetrf* on *A* (does LU factorization) and then *zgetrs* on *A* and *b* (solves linear system of LU matrix) from Lapack/MKL. 
But this ends up with error, *zgetrf* can't factorize the matrix *A* and says that it is singular. So I have called SVD on it - *zgesvd*. And this works. But the eigenvalues of the matrix *A* are as follows:

(2885.24776463951,8.34234423485148)

(1.41421356237310,1.41421356237310)

(1.41421356237309,0.144427825453540)

(1.257628062933306E-014,0.000000000000000E+000)

(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)

(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)

(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)

(0.000000000000000E+000,0.000000000000000E+000)

Can I find where is the problem for *zgetrf* to factorize? I think such eigenvalues say that the matrix A is only of rank 4 in spite of having physical dimension 8 x 8... can I estimate which lines are dependent?
Thank you very much

Comment: I would say the matrix has rank 3. A singular value of 1e-14 is, for all practical reasons, zero when there are other eigenvalues of size 1 or large.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, this seems me too small as well, unfortunately :(

Comment: This question may be interesting for you as well: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2510/null-space-of-a-rectangular-dense-matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume you've given us the singular values from SVD, not the eigenvalues (they are related, but not the same).  You are right: this means your matrix is rank 4 despite being an 8x8 matrix.  The SVD has already given you everything you need: the first four left and right singular vectors are a basis that represents your operator as a 4x4 matrix.  If the matrix A is static, then you **could** transform your whole calculation in to that those bases and proceed with a non-singular matrix.  A better idea is probably to use the SVD to form a [pseudo-inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of $A$.  Recall the SVD of $A$:
$$ A = U \Sigma V^* $$
where $U$, $V$ are unitary and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with non-negative values (but some zeros, as in your case).  The diagonal elements of $\Sigma$ are ordered and called the singular values.  You can construct a pseudo-inverse as:
$$A^\dagger = V \Sigma^\dagger U^* \quad \Sigma^\dagger_{ii} = \Sigma_{ii}^{-1} \text{ if } \Sigma_{ii} > 0, \text{ else } 0 $$

Comment: yes, many thanks! I will do it. Many thanks for your help. Yes, the values are singular values.